# Trying to write to one table with multiple forms in Access

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access-2010

After searching around the forums I can find multiple issues with having several tables and one form, however I have the inverse problem.  I have four separate forms that are all linked to the same table.  No two forms edit the same variable on the table.

If people open up a single form, save it, close it, then move on to the next form the database works as intended.  However, some people open up all the forms and forget to save/close the one beforehand.  At this point, Access refuses to save the file stating that 'Another user has this file open' since the table is open in another form, even though no variable should overwrite each other.

Is there any workaround for this?  I'd just like to have people be able to save their entered data from several forms to the same table.  There will be no point in time that two people would access this table simultaneously, I just want to make sure we can save the data if someone opens multiple forms at once.

Answer (score 0):

First, in a MS Access database multiple users can have same forms open. The only Read/Write issue would occur if users are working in the same record. Whoever enters the record first and begins updating would have the record-locked for him/her and users afterwards would get the warning message until the record is saved (or dirty event is removed). Users may be able to view but not be able to edit.

So your issue may be more an operational than a programming one. Try to organize users to manage specific records at a certain time or coordinate add/update work between team members. Of course this would be impossible if you run over a large company network with hundreds of users or online.

Still another solution would involve migrating all separate forms as subforms into one main form, so all corresponding records align at same time. But normally, subforms are reserved for join tables and not same table record sources. You can use tabs if space is an issue. This does not stop the record-locking issue but at least reduces the chances of it since less records are spread across separate objects. In fact this may prove to be better as users can move back and forth to other variables of the same record for reference on one form instead of opening/closing other forms or keeping the other ones opened.

Finally, it is highly advised if working in a multiple user environment and especially since you are connecting ODBC to systems like MySQL to split your database between FrontEnd (*linked* tables, forms, queries, macros, modules) and BackEnd (only tables). This setup prevents corruption, efficiently runs systems as only data is sent across the network and not whole application items, and overall fosters a better multi-user environment. Each user can have a copy of the FE on their local machines but all will connect to one BE on a shared network. To help, Access 2007-2013 has a button for this on the Ribbon under Database Tools.

Answer (score -1):

I've used a dashboard that displayed buttons to open the forms needed and then used `yourform.showdialog()` to open up other forms in C#. This will make it so the user cannot use other forms until the form that is open is closed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39wcs2dh(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry...didn't realize that i needed to do that. I will remember next time.